# Auto post on friends wall when user logged in using Graph API for first time

Tags: facebook-graph-api

When first time a user logged in through Facebook Graph API APP, whether any auto post will be triggered to others wall on user's behalf regarding new APP first Login?

APP is given permission to read_stream, publish_actions.

Answer (score 0):

That is not allowed and not possible for many obvious reasons:

- You are not allowed to autopost, not even on the wall of the authorized user. Every single post has to be approved by the user.
- You are not allowed to prefill the message, it must be 100% user generated.
- You can´t post to the wall of friends (anymore), that would be spam anyway.

...also, you will not get read_stream approved, but you would not need that permission for posting anyway:

> This permission is granted to apps building a Facebook-branded client on platforms where Facebook is not already available. For example, Android and iOS apps will not be approved for this permission. In addition, Web, Desktop, in-car and TV apps will not be granted this permission.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.2#reference-read_stream

Don´t create spammy Apps. User friends don´t care if the user just started using your App. You may want to read this too: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app